# Genymotion: error "Unable to start the virtual device"

Tags: xamarin, genymotion

I can't run the virtual android.
I get the error

> Unable to start the virtual device.

[image]

Comment: did you read the FAQ?   Did you review the logs?

Comment: You can try to use android emulator that VS provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/